# Add image carousel indicators to jQuery image slideshow without bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an image carousel without bootstrap. I have it completed but want to add the carousel indicators on the bottom which specify which slide it is currently on similar to how http://www.automatic.com has it.

My jsfiddle code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/x8rgm89z/

Javascript code:

```
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
     setInterval(function(){
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
     5000);
```

Comment: Have you had look at Orbit slider? It is exactly what you are looking for, very easy to implement and I've tried it once on my own project and it works perfectly

Comment: [anawesomejqcarousel](http://www.anantkpal.in/anawesomejqcarousel) here I have given a option for callback function. This should do for you.

Comment: @AnantPal where is the code?

Comment: [code at github ]https://github.com/anantkpal/anawesomejqcarousel/blob/master/src/anAwesomejQCarousel.js

Answer (score 0):

http://zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider

the orbit slider is a good alternative, see link above ^